# How can I create a .PS, .SVG, & .PNG writing to a Graphics object?

Tags: c#, .net, svg, postscript

I want to create different vector and raster files by writing to a Graphics object. Is there a way to do this where it will provide a Graphics object I can build up the same and get each of these outputs?

(Java has this built around the Graphics2D object, I'm hoping .NET has the same.)

Comment: Are you able to show a [mcve] of your progress so far?

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/vector-graphics-overview help?

Comment: @mjwills - no I don't have an example - I'm asking if this can be done and if so how.

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you're up for the challenge of putting **builkt** in .Net you can use https://www.ikvm.net

Comment: @JeremyThompson - we actually use IKVM. However, for this case the approach in Java is for some reason dog slow under IKVM/TextLayout.

Answer (score 1):

The "cairo" open source library was always built on these premises - although you'd have to build a separate object (with a different drawing context) for both raster and vector outputs, the API for drawing in both contexts is identical (so, you just have to duplicate all drawing calls).

I had never tried its bindings to .net, though, but I supose they are ok:
https://forums.dotnetfoundation.org/t/the-cairo-c-binding-has-been-ported-to-net-core/2075  , https://github.com/zwcloud/CairoSharp

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Bitmap object for raster graphics. For example

```
using(Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100,100))
{
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        // draw to graphics object
        ...
        // save the image. the second parameter specifies the format
        // you can use bmp, emf, gif, png, jpeg, ...
        bitmap .Save("pathToFile",ImageFormat.Bmp)

    }
}
```

Vector graphics are more complicated. You will probably need to look for libraries for each vector graphics format.